# Wordpress Set Custom 404 Error Page

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

New to Wordpress and confused. There is a page to my site that is not part of any of the pages listed in the Dashboard, such as , Home , About, etc. It is still listed with the correct begining ex: "mysite.com/.....". I have searched all through the dashboard and can't find the url listed anywhere. This doesnt make much sense to me. I was wondering if there is a way to just set the url to a 404 error, possibly, but not necessarily, with a redirect to another page.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: need more info, it could be a page associated with a category or wordpress tag

Comment: Willing to give you anything you need.

Comment: how about the url to the error page

Comment: Well the page doesn't give me a 404 error, it has content, and just want to set it to be a 404, if possible. Finding the page anywhere has yielded no results after hours of searching.

Comment: why don't you just make the page private so no one can see the content

Comment: The page itself is not an actual page that was created in the backend of Wordpress.

Comment: if it is a file outside of wordpress just send the error using php in the header

Comment: Ok, that sounds doable. Can you point me in the right direction to going about that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP to send headers with error codes, this is one way of doing what you want. see mroe details about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php